# Wild card sub domain redirection with Azure

Tags: azure, redirect, dns, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

I have registered my domain at **Bigrock**.

Say I have a domain **abc.com**

**Requirement**: Now I want to do wildcard domain redirection anything like 
**aaa.abc.com** 
**bbb.abc.com** 
**ccc.abc.com**

All the above url should hit the same application which I hosted for **abc.com**

Process that I have done so far..
I added a A record in DNS management portal as below

```
    *.abc.com       111.221.95.27       Active
```

Hosted my application with **Azure**

**HOSTNAMES ASSIGNED TO SITE**

> www.abc.com 
>  abc.azurewebsites.net

But it is redirecting to 404 error page if I browse anything apart from **www.abc.com** / **abc.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it is redirecting to 404 error page if I browse anything apart from www.abc.com / abc.com

After configured the wild card sub domain redirection, all your sub domain will point the inbound IP address of Azure website. Since Azure websites are hosted on shared platform. We have to configure all the hosted names which used to access the website on Azure Web App Custom domain panel. Please check whether abc.com and www.abc.com hostnames are configured successfully in Azure portal.

[image]

> HOSTNAMES ASSIGNED TO SITE
>   www.abc.com

Before adding hostname, Azure Web App will verify the ownership of the hostname. For www.abc.com hostname, Please add a CNAME record pointing to yoursitename.azurewebsites.net in your custom domain provider site. For example,

```
CNAME www yoursitename.azurewebsites.net
```

[image]

Comment: Any updates? Have you tried my suggestions? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi thanks for you effort, all above stuffs were done already.

Comment: Do you mean the host names(abc.com and www.abc.com) are listed in custom domain panel of Azure portal? If yes, please use some DNS lookup online tool(for example https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx) to check whether the host names have pointed the IP address successfully.

Comment: Yes but I missed *.abc.com in Azure custom domain panel

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue by adding **wild card entry in Azure**

**Previous:** 
**HOSTNAMES ASSIGNED TO SITE**

> www.abc.com 
>  abc.azurewebsites.net

**Now:** 
**HOSTNAMES ASSIGNED TO SITE**

> www.abc.com 
>  abc.azurewebsites.net 
> *.abc.com